# How to implement two-legged OAuth in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

Recently, Yahoo closed their public API (for getting weather data) and switched to two-legged OAuth 1 authentication. My question is: how do I implement it in Swift? How do I pass parameters in a header, etc.?

I've got a Client ID (consumer key) and a Client Secret (consumer secret) for my application. Also, what url can I provide as a callback url?

**UPDATE**

It'd be great if I could receive an answer that doesn't suppose using non-standard libraries/frameworks.